# How to only mask middle part of Ruby string?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, ruby-on-rails-4, gsub

I have this:

```
phone = "+60123453180"
p = phone.gsub!(/(?=...).(?=....)/, '*')
=> "********3180"
```

How to only mask `345` and return `+6012***3180`?

Comment: How do you define the "middle" part?

Comment: Do you know length of the phone number ?

Comment: @pramod I believe it is `phone.length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
phone = "+60123453180"
phone.tap { |p| p[5...8] = "****" }
#⇒ "+6012****3180"
```

Play with `5...8` range to modify an amount of symbols to be substituted.

**NB** Your original code modified the phone *inplace*, hence the code above also modifies it inplace.

To keep the original value intact, one might use `dup`:

```
phone.dup.tap { |p| p[5...8] = "****" }
#⇒ "+6012****3180"
phone
#⇒ "+60123453180"
```

Comment: I am not sure if we can assume that the string is always 12 chars long and that the replacement in the middle is 4 chars. What about if the phone number is only 10 chars or 14?

Comment: @spickermann Note “play with range” line above. Nothing prevents us of making it `s.length/3...s.length/3*2`.

Comment: I like this solution. Thanks @mudasobwa!

Comment: Why use #tap?  Also, did you mean to substitute three asterisks, as the OP did, instead four?

Comment: @WayneConrad `tap` is to return the whole number. I did not pay much attention to how many symbols to subst, it is a pattern shown.

Answer (score 3):

I would start with something like this:

```
phone = '+60123453180'
phone.sub(/(?<=\A.{4})(.*)(?=.{4}\z)/) { |match| '*' * match.length }
#=> "+601****3180"
```

Comment: Regular expression here is a redundant overkill.

Comment: I would not sound that categorical, but the lookaheads really are a bit of an overkill here.

Comment: Thanks @spickermann for the help. I really appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

To modify `phone` in place:

```
phone[5..7] = "***"
p phone    # => "+6012***180"
```

If every obscured character should have a corresponding asterisk, as in your example, then it may be better to represent that explicitly:

```
range_to_cover = 5..7
phone[range_to_cover] = "*" * range_to_cover.size
```